# Looking for suggestions for an wide angle lens for Nikon FX

Tags: lens, nikon, wide-angle, full-frame, samyang

I recently upgraded to full frame by getting a Nikon D600. I would like to know what would be an ideal wide angle Lens for this FX camera of mine.

Nikon wide angle lenses are very expensive, so I have been looking into third party lens makers like Rokinon, Samyanag, and Bower.

I have listed the lenses I have looked at.  I was wondering whether someone could suggest me something in regards to this

Budget: I plan to spend less than $500

[Bower 14mm f/2.8](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=880768&Q=&is=REG&A=details)

[Rokinon FE14M-N 14mm F2.8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VS9UP4)

Comment: Bytheway, those three are the same lens. Only that Bower has focus confirmation chip, but otherwise Bower, Rokinon and Samyang are all the same lens from the same manufacturer. I have that lens too, mine is under Samyang brand. http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/reviews/lenses/samyang14.html

Comment: See also [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/42142/1943) on the Samyang 8mm fisheye.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the other FX wide-angle prime question -- the previous question is _very_ specific to a certain situation in the past. But.... now that you know those lenses are the same, maybe this could be rephrased? Please see [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for some tips on how to phrase equipment questions so they get good answers (and don't get closed.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a wide angle lens on a full frame camera such as yours is between 24-35mm. The lenses that you link to are all 14mm [*ulta* wide angle lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/327/what-is-an-ultra-wide-lens). It is also important to note that they are not fisheye type but instead are rectilinear lenses.

Another important point to note is that all three lenses you mention are essentially the same lenses repackaged under different brand names.

If you in fact only need a wide angle lens, your options open up quite a bit. If you need a ultra wide angle lens but also don't mind a fisheye option, again you have more options. If you *must* have a rectilinear ultra wide angle lens for $500USD or less; unfortunately you won't find anything but what you have listed or other very cheap poor options.

What I would recommend if you are happy with 18mm is extending your budget slightly and buying the Nikon 18-35mm f/3.5-4.5G ED AF-S. It can be had currently for around $750 and is an excellent option.

Another option would be a bit of a DIY job but very doable. You could buy the Tokina 11-16mm f/2.8 and simply not use filters or a lens hood and still get good images at 15mm or so, but I have not tried this personally and I'm not sure if you need filters.

The Nikon 14-24mm f/2.8 and the Nikon 16-35mm f/4 VR are great reasons to buy the Nikon system in general. If you really are serious about wide angle photography; it might be a good investment to make.